# Optimising a Series Asymetrical Wireless Radio Connection

Tags: wireless

I have a series of radio sites are connected as follows:

A-B-C-D

Sites have the following radios:

A - AP- rocket m5

B -AP, STATION 2x nanostation

C- AP, Station 2x nano station

D-Station 1 x nano station

The data to be transfered is nearly entirely in one direction- D->A, with each site producing data and sending it to A.

Couple Questions:

1. What optimizations can be made that allow assyemtrical information to transfer faster? (packet size, Timeouts, etc)
2. What optimizations can be made that will help speed up Daisy chain style connections such as this one?

Comment: This site is new (still in beta) and I am not sure if we have any Ubiquiti experts here yet. IIRC the AirMax products are proprietary wireless devices, not IEEE standards based.  I hate to point you elsewhere, but you may find better luck posting at the [Ubiquiti Community forums](http://community.ubnt.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/Forums).  I hope to be proven wrong though and hope you get a great answer here.

Comment: nobody said anything about AirMax(tm). everything listed can operate as standard 802.11b/g hardware.

Comment: @RickyBeam, RocketM and NanoStation are two of the hardware offerings in the AirMax line of products.  While they *can* operate in the same unlicensed frequencies and have some similarities to 802.11, they do not conform to the IEEE standards, nor can you connect an 802.11 device to them.  I haven't used them personally in a deployment and could be wrong so please feel free to provide links if this is the case, but that was my understanding the last time I considered them for a customer's deployment.

Comment: I've used numerous nano stations for public wifi. yes, they make models that operate outside the usual a and b bands. Read the datasheets; the 2.4GHz and 5GHz devices can operate in wifi or airmax modes. (in fact dd-wrt is supported on some of them)

Comment: @RickyBeam, thank you for your first hand knowledge and appreciate your input, for as I mentioned I haven't used them. The datasheet does indeed mention 11a/11g/11n (took me a bit to find though as it only appears in the tables at -90 degrees). Only other mention of wifi/802.11 I found in the data sheet was this line: "Unlike standard WiFi protocol, Ubiquiti's Time Division Multiple Access (TDMA) AirMax protocol <snip>." This was much more prominent and when I had discussed this product with them they only mentioned that AirMax was better than 802.11 (and not that it supported it as well).

Comment: Is all the links wireless ?   e.g. Will B and C be repeating incoming traffic out  again over wifi ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Airmax is about the time slots, and can help you maximize them and not allow lower quality clients to use up all the time by (re)transmitting.

For your purpose, turn it off I think. There's always the debate about airmax on or off on PtP (point to point) links.

Use AP-WDS and STATION-WDS modes on the devices. This will make the point to point connections function similarly to if you were running ethernet between each point.

You want to optimize noise floor and CCQ %. This will help the most in throughput.

So, some questions. The rocket at A, does it have an omni antenna or a sector or a dish?

Why not a rocket at the other end of the PtP link between A and B? That seems like your "backhaul" link?

Are all of these devices M series, the older models, or the new AC models?

I work for an ISP that uses Ubiquiti as part of our product mix. Although not an expert I think I can help you in this scenario.

Comment: As I understood there no specific tuning for asymmetric traffic. Only generic tuning to improve CCQ and throughput.